# Android facebook graph post on multiple users same message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I use facebook open graph feed dialog in Andorid to post on friend wall. I use code above to post on friend wall.

Is there way to post this message to multiple users in same dialog (same time)?

```
        params.putString("to", friendID); 

         params.putString("name",name);             
         params.putString("description",description);
         params.putString("picture", picture);
         params.putString("link", link);
         params.putString("caption", caption);


Utility.mFacebook.dialog(this, "feed", params, new PostOnFriendWallRequestListener());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Send To dialog

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

You can specify one user in the `TO` where your user will then be able to include more users or groups to send the payload to.

note,

> A user ID or username to which to send the message. Once the dialog
>   comes up, the user can specify additional users, Facebook groups, and
>   email addresses to which to send the message. Sending content to a
>   Facebook group will post it to the group's wall.